# Remote logon through Powershell and task execution

Tags: authentication, powershell, execution

Is it possible to logon to the remote machine using Powershell, and to execute scheduled task or batch file, which contains CodedUI tests? I have tried Invoke-Command, but CodedUI test cannot be executed because it has no control over the desktop. Autologon is enabled on the machine, and all I need is to remotely login to it, and execute scheduled task. Is that possible?

Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an interactive desktop session, you will need to use RDP or similar. When you create a remote PowerShell session, or use `Invoke-Command`, you're creating a *new* session, not connecting to an existing one. And there's no GUI to associate with it.

Comment: Yes, I need something like RDP, but through command line - to be able to initiate session from other machine using Powershell. Is that possible?

Comment: You can *initiate* new session (`New-PSSession`), but you won't be able to attach to another session that was created in a different way.